# External validation of nomogram

Tags: r, logistic, validation, rms, calibration

I am tasked with externally validating a nomogram predicting a binary outcome using our internal data. I do not have the regression coefficients of the original prediction model--I have access to the derived online score calculator. I can input my patients' clinical data in to generate probability of the binary outcome per patient. Are there any software tools I can use to construct validation plots and indices when I DO NOT have the stored output of the original prediction model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you help us understand what you mean by "nomogram" and its connection with the "derived online score calculator"?  Do you have direct access to the nomogram or not?  Regardless, why isn't the score calculator capable of reproducing the "stored output of the original prediction model"?

Comment: Hi, whuber--thanks for your response and for feedback on how to better construct my question. I have direct access to the nomogram calculator, in that I can input patient and tumor characteristics into an online calculator and it spits out a probability of relapse within 5 years. I do not have model parameter coefficients as I would if I had constructed the model.

Comment: The part I'm not understanding is what you really need: if you have software that will produce the model predictions, isn't that sufficient for checking it?  Indeed, it is a property of most regression models that you can recover their coefficients by re-running them using the predicted values only (instead of the actual values).  (With generalized linear models such as logistic regression, which you might have used, this is possible even though the outcomes are binary and the predictions are probabilities.)